# javascript replace / with \/

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am trying to escape all forward slashes in a string.

objective:

```
convert('path/to/awesomeness/{plus}/{special-characters!}/')
'path\/to\/awesomeness\/{plus}\/{special-characters!}\/'
```

result 1:

```
'path/to/awesomeness/{plus}/{special-characters!}/'.replace(/\//g, '\/')
'path/to/awesomeness/{plus}/{special-characters!}/'
```

result 2:

```
'path/to/awesomeness/{plus}/{special-characters!}/'.replace(/\//g, '\\/')
'path\\/to\\/awesomeness\\/{plus}\\/{special-characters!}\\/'
```

In the node console, it gives the above outputs. Check : https://i.stack.imgur.com/X471f.png. How can I replace `/` with `\/`?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what have you done, what did fail, what do you exactly want?

Comment: The question is very clear. Objective: shows expected behavior. Result 1: shows first thing attempted, and the output. Result 2: show second thing attempted, and the output. Just copy/paste it into the node repl, and hit return.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/J0XQ51t.png

Comment: If I copy/paste your 2nd attempt into the js console, it gives me the output you want.  Your problem is confusion about string escaping of backslashes.

Comment: People, this looks like a valid question. Please stop downvoting and please remove "on hold".

Comment: thefourtheye, thanks very much. I was starting to feel frustrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt has actually worked fine.  The problem is how to read a string that has escaped characters in it, as shown in the Node console.  If you want to put an apostrophe in the middle of a string, you have to escape it like this:

```
var s = 'I\'m cool';
```

And in the same way, when you want to put a backslash in a string, you have to escape that, too:

```
var s = 'This is a single backslash: \\';
```

So, if you did this: `'/'.replace(/\//g, '\\')` you'd get a single-character string - a backslash.  Node chooses to show you string *as you'd have to type it to make it valid in code* (ie an escaped backslash, which looks like 2 backslashes), not as it actually is.

The Chrome console does not do this, nor does Firefox.  Try it there and see the difference.